# TeamCity restore

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I am trying to move TeamCity from one server to another. I have got it all installed on the new server and have run the instructions in the help file:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Restoring+TeamCity+Data+from+Backup

I am running TeamCity 5.1.4 on both servers.

I got a success message on the maintaindb command and then restarted the TeamCity Web Server in services. However when I login the projects etc haven't been moved over.

Am I missing something obvious? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems "configure new TeamCity installation to use proper TeamCity Data Directory and database" (from [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/How+To...#HowTo...-copyserver)) is a key to your case.

Comment: Yep, you got it. I had 2 .BuildServer folders and needed to identify the correct one.

Comment: JetBrains also got back to me here : http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5274764#5274764

Answer (score 2):

Recently moved/upgraded our server and not had any issues.

We did not use this method though - as we using the default db, we just moved that "as is".

Presumably your backup looks "good"?

Have you tried the TeamCity forums, I find them quite responsive:

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/teamcity

Comment: The backup looks "good". It was not an overly complicated set-up anyway. How did you do your move? Maybe I should try that, I am using the HQL database. I will try the TeamCity forums as well. I did look for answers but posted on here first.

Comment: Just also posted on JetBrains forums as suggested. Will update here if I get a response.